# How to restore Firebug Command Line History

Tags: firebug

I was working on a script in the Console > Command Line and it somehow crashed Firebug. Firebug would no longer run it so I restarted the browser. All the code I was working on was lost. Is there a file that I can check to see if my code was saved to it?

In the future I'd like to know if I can persist my Command Line History.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the command line history is not persisted between browser sessions. There is a [request for it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/4415), but because the [Firebug project is officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/), it won't be implemented anymore.

Luckily, the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) do store the command history between browser sessions. And it even works when the browser crashes in between.